# SSIS Derived Column Transformation if not blank

Tags: ssis, derived-column

i have added a Derived Column task that adds " at the beginning of a field and " at the end of a field but i only want to apply it if the field is not null/not blank and contains characters

my expression is, this works and correctly ads "" to the field but i only want to apply if there is data in the field

```
"\"" + fieldname + "\""
```

but i cant work out how to only apply where field is not blank
i tried something like this but is did not work

```
ISNULL([fieldname]) == FALSE ? "\"" + fieldname + "\"" : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ISNULL` this way

```
!ISNULL([fieldname]) ? "\"" + fieldname + "\"" : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

you need both tests.

```
!ISNULL([fieldname]) && length(fieldname)>0 ? "\"" + fieldname + "\"" : ""
```

or a nested IF

```
!ISNULL([fieldname]) ?
     length(fieldname)>0 ? "\"" + fieldname + "\"" : ""
     : ""
```